# Getting pronunciation of a word using Google Translate API

Tags: audio, text-to-speech, google-translate, phonetics

I am trying to save the pronunciation of a French word into a .wav or .mp3 file.

I was wondering if there was anywhere on the Google Translate API (since it has a pronunciation functionality) that allows me to achieve this objective. Other libraries would work too.

Comment: Seems you could do a file query on something like that: http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=word. Ie: http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q=Ce%20chocolat%20est%20tr%C3%A8s%20tr%C3%A8s%20tr%C3%A8s%20tr%C3%A8s%20bon Trouble is, there are some "google abuse" tests, checking if you are an human, and limiting robots. I got it after ~12 rapid hand queries

Comment: Any alternatives available?

Answer (score 9):

Since this question was asked, it's gotten much harder to "scrape" MP3s from Google Translate, but Google has (finally) set up a [TTS API](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/). Interestingly it is billed in input characters, with the first 1 or 4 million input characters per month being free (depending on whether you use WaveNet or old school voices)

Nowadays to do this using `gcloud` on the command line (versus building this into an app) you would do roughly as follows (I'm paraphrasing the [TTS quick start](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol)). You need `base64`, `curl`, `gcloud`, and `jq` for this walkthrough.

1. Create a project on the GCP console, or run something like `gcloud projects create example-throwaway-tts`
2. [Enable billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project) for the project. Do this even if you don't intend to exceed the freebie quota.
3. Use the GCP console to [enable the TTS API](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=texttospeech.googleapis.com) for the project you just set up.
4. Use the console *again,* this time to [make a new service account](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey).

   - Use any old name
   - Don't give it a role. You'll get a warning. This is okay.
   - Select key type JSON if it isn't already selected
   - Click `Create`
   - Hold onto the JSON file that your browser downloads
5. Set an environment variable to point at that file, e.g. `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="~/Downloads/service-account-file.json"`
6. Get the appropriate access token:

   1. Tell `gcloud` to use that new project: `gcloud config set project example-throwaway-tts`
   2. Set a variable `TTS_ACCESS_TOKEN=gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`
7. Put together a JSON request. I'll give an example below. For this example we'll call it `request.json`
8. Lastly, run the following

   ```
    curl \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer "$TTS_ACCESS_TOKEN \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
   --data-raw @request.json \
   "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize" \
   | jq '.audioContent' \
   | base64 --decode > very_simple_example.mp3
   ```

What this does is to

- authenticate using the default access token for the project you set up
- set the content type to JSON (so that `jq` can extract the payload)
- use `request.json` as the data to send using `curl`'s `--data-raw` flag
- extract the value of `audioContent` from the response
- `base64` decode that content
- save the whole mess as an MP3

Contents of `request.json` follow. You can see where to insert your desired text, adjust [the voice](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1/text/synthesize#voiceselectionparams) or change output formats via [audioConfig](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1/text/synthesize#audioconfig):

```
{
  'input':{
    'text':'very simple example'
  },
  'voice':{
    'languageCode':'en-gb',
    'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
    'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
  },
  'audioConfig':{
      'audioEncoding':'MP3'
  }
}
```

**Original Answer**

As Hugolpz alludes, if you know the word or phrase you want (via a previous Translate API call), you can get MP3s from a URL like http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=Bonjour&tl=fr

Note that `&tl=fr` ensures that you get French instead of the default English.

You will need to rate-limit yourself, but if you're looking for a small number of words or phrases you should be fine.

Comment: It's not really an "API" if it's undocumented, but there's a bit more detail about this here: http://ctrlq.org/code/19147-text-to-speech-php

Comment: Unfortunately the TTS functionality has since been CAPTCHA protected, so there's no way to programmatically do this anymore using the Google Translate API.

Answer (score 4):

Similar functionality is provided by the [Speech Synthesis API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk-Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API) (under development). Third-party libraries are already there, such as [ResponsiveVoice.JS](http://responsivevoice.org/).

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful. Google cloud also have a service for that matter too. https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/pricing